# Python. Remove from array (presented as list of lists) rows and columns by condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array presented as list of lists, and I need ro remove all rows and then columns where values are greater then some variable.
I can't find out myself how to do it.
All I could do is something like:

```
rowNum =0
for row in self.Table:
    rowIsValid = False
    for value in row:
        if not value is None and (value > 0.35 and not value == 1):
            rowIsValid = True
    if not rowIsValid:
        self.Table =  numpy.delete(self.Table, (rowNum), axis=0)
        #self.Table.pop(row)
    rowNum+=1
```

And i'ts just for rows. And it didn't work(
How do remove columns - I cant even imagine.

Data example
Input:

```
 1.0 None 0.333 0.166 None
 0.4 1.0  0.541 0.4   0.3
 0.1 0.41 1.0   0.23  0.11
```

Output (for example i need remove rows and columns where all values are smaller than 0.3 and not (1 not included in calcualtions))

```
0.4 1.0  0.541 0.4  
0.1 0.41 1.0   0.23
```

Comment: Please provide a sample input and expected output.

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25391473/963881 ?

Comment: I agree with REACHUS - this is very nearly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/25391473/963881 ...

Comment: There data sorted by just 1 column, and i need data that will be sorted by all values in all rows than all values in all columns.

Comment: Always post sample input and desired output apart from your attempted code. ;-)  *+1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array looks something like this:

```
>>> arr = array([[ 1.   ,    nan,  0.333,  0.166,    nan],
       [ 0.4  ,  1.   ,  0.541,  0.4  ,  0.3  ],
       [ 0.1  ,  0.41 ,  1.   ,  0.23 ,  0.11 ]])
```

Then first set all `nan` values to `True` as they don't fit out criteria.

```
>>> arr[np.isnan(arr)] = True
```

Now get an array of booleans where `True` means the items that match our criteria, now if all items in a row or column are `True` then we should ignore that row or column:

```
>>> temp = (arr == 1.0) | (arr < 0.35)
>>> temp
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Get only those rows which contains at least one `False`:

```
>>> rows = ~np.all(temp, axis=1)
>>> rows
array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Same as rows, but on different axis:

```
>>> cols = ~np.all(temp, axis=0)
>>> cols
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Now use simple indexing and slicing to get the required items:

```
>>> arr[rows][:, cols]
array([[ 0.4  ,  1.   ,  0.541,  0.4  ],
       [ 0.1  ,  0.41 ,  1.   ,  0.23 ]])
```

Comment: At fact, I did clarification, and None can be equaled to 0, but your idea is good. I'll try to use it. Thanks a lot. It's creative approach)