# How to delete specific values from numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray that looks like:

```
[[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[225 224 228],
[163 164 174],
[205 212 229],
[116 130 153],
[ 81 101 132],
[ 34  56  92],
[  2  16  35],
[ 33  44  64],
[ 38  49  71],
[ 63  75  99],
[ 76  88 116],
[ 45  62  95],
[ 29  50  88],
[ 18  40  82],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0]]
```

I want to delete all the zero elements i.e. `[0,0,0]`. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove rows from a numpy array based on multiple conditions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380255/how-do-i-remove-rows-from-a-numpy-array-based-on-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`np.delete()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) and `np.where()` to get the elements where the condition is satisfied as :

```
del_arr = np.delete(arr, np.where(arr == [0, 0, 0]), axis=0)
print del_arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[225 224 228],
[163 164 174],
[205 212 229],
[116 130 153],
[ 81 101 132],
[ 34  56  92],
[  2  16  35],
[ 33  44  64],
[ 38  49  71],
[ 63  75  99],
[ 76  88 116],
[ 45  62  95],
[ 29  50  88],
[ 18  40  82],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0],
[  0   0   0])


zeros = np.all(np.equal(a, 0), axis=1)
array[~zeros]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data[(data[:,1] & data[:, 2] & data[:, 0]).astype(bool)]
```