# Delete specific values in 2-Dimension array - Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
```

I have two arrays of size n (to simplify, I use in this example n = 2):

```
A = array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
```

B has two dimensions with n time a random integer: 1, 2 or 3.

Let's pretend:

```
B = array([[1],[3]])
```

What is the most pythonic way to subtract B from A in order to obtain C, `C = array([2,3],[1,2])` ?

I tried to use `np.subtract` but due to the broadcasting rules I do not obtain C. I do not want to use mask or indices but element's values. I also tried to use `np.delete`, `np.where` without success.
Thank you.

Comment: What if there are duplicates in any row of `A`?

Comment: In my case, there is no duplicate. But if there is let 's say substract the first iteration.

Comment: Check this link, hope it will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557558/how-to-delete-specific-values-from-numpy-ndarray

Comment: And what if no match is found? For ex. : `B = array([[5],[3]])`?

Comment: In my case, there will alway be a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work and should be quite Pythonic:

```
dd=[[val for val in A[i] if val not in B[i]] for i in xrange(len(A))]
```

Comment: Thank you. It does work with 'range' instead of 'xrange'.

Comment: I am still using Python2.X, therefore `xrange`... Glad it worked!