# Delete rows where specific columns contain some value

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array, consisting of 8 values per line:

```
data = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3, 5, 6, 7, 15, 27],
                 [ 5,  6,  7, 5, 10, 12, 23, 52],
                 [ 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27,44]])
```

I would like to delete every row where `data[:,2:5]` is equal to zero (so where all columns between 2 and 5 equal zero)

I have found that using the following *works*, but it's a bit of a mouthful and I can't really expand to more columns:

```
data_nonzero = np.delete(data, np.where(np.bitwise_and(np.bitwise_and((data[:,2]==0), (data[:,3]==0)), np.bitwise_and((data[:,4]==0), (data[:,5]==0)) ) )[0], 0)
```

I have tried something like:

```
new_a = np.delete(data, np.s_[:,2:5] == 0, axis=0)
```

But that doesn't seem to work:

> boolean array argument obj to delete must be one dimensional

Preferably, it would check for 2 conditions for the 4 columns in each row. Something like:

```
new_a = np.delete(data, np.where(np.s_[:,2:5] == 0 | np.s_[:,2:5] > 50000), axis=0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove rows from a numpy array based on multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380255/how-do-i-remove-rows-from-a-numpy-array-based-on-multiple-conditions)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Unfortunately not. I have already seen that post. I'll end up the same place I am not: With a huge statement (although it can be split into minor statements). Was really hoping there was another way. I don't necessarily need multiple conditions, but one condition against multiple (but not all) columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution:
data.csv file contains:

```
var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7
x,x,0,0,0,0,x
x,x,0,0,0,0,x
x,x,65535,65535,65535,65535,x
x,x,0,40,116,3,x
x,x,65535,95,208,2,x
x,x,3,147,277,2,x
x,x,2,203,325,2,x
```

Code:

```
data = genfromtxt(filename[0], delimiter=',',skip_header=1)

print('------ Original data ------')
print(data[0:7,:])


new_a = np.delete(data, ~np.any(data[:,2:5], axis=1),axis=0)
print('------ Rows where data[:,2:5] == 0 removed ------')
print(new_a[0:5,:])

new_b = np.delete(new_a, np.all(new_a[:,2:5] > 60000,axis=1),axis=0)
print('------ Rows where data[:,2:5] > 60000 removed ------')
print(new_b[0:4,:])
```

Result:

```
------ Original data ------
[[x x 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 x]
[x x 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 x]
[x x 65535.00 65535.00 65535.00 65535.00 x]
[x x 0.00 40.00 116.00 3.00 x]
[x x 65535.00 95.00 208.00 2.00 x]
[x x 3.00 147.00 277.00 2.00 x]
[x x 2.00 203.00 325.00 2.00 x]]

------ Rows where data[:,2:5] == 0 removed ------
[[x x 65535.00 65535.00 65535.00 65535.00 x]
[x x 0.00 40.00 116.00 3.00 x]
[x x 65535.00 95.00 208.00 2.00 x]
[x x 3.00 147.00 277.00 2.00 x]
[x x 2.00 203.00 325.00 2.00 x]]

------ Rows where data[:,2:5] > 60000 removed ------
[[66.01 -46.05 0.00 40.00 116.00 3.00 x]
[66.01 -39.46 65535.00 95.00 208.00 2.00 x]
[66.01 -32.87 3.00 147.00 277.00 2.00 x]
[66.01 -26.28 2.00 203.00 325.00 2.00 x]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I would just use boolean indexing with the negation of your condition, namely,

```
>>> data[(data[:, 2:6] != 0).any(axis=1), ...]
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7, 15, 27],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  5, 10, 12, 23, 52]])
```

In other words, you want to select the rows that contain any value that is not zero.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but your statement doesn't remove zero-rows in Python 3.8. 
Furthermore: I don't want to remove any row that has a zero in one of any spot between column 2 and 5; only the rows where all columns contain 0.

Zero's are allowed to exist in the array; just not in all 4 spots simultaneously

Comment: @KristianSlot what do you mean? That's *exactly* what this code does, except that you'd have to change the condition to `data[:, 2:6]` if you meant columns 2 through 5 *inclusive*. What is the output you *expect*???

Comment: @KristianSlot the code above doesn't remove any row that has a zero in any spot between column 2 and 5 (inclusive), it selects all the rows that have any non-zero value in it, i.e. *excluding all throws that have all zeros for those columns*